# React Native - Android ( Communication between Java and Javascript )

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native

I have a React Native app in which I embedded some Android native component (chart) using SimpleViewManager that has it's own Java events. Now I need to connect Java's methods requestData and receiveData to functions in Javascript that will receive these requests and return data fetched via websocket. 
I'm having trouble with a simple call to JS function from Java method with some argumens.
How do I do that?

React Native's official documentation wasn't a great help.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a moment to review the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour , 
How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , and more specifically, 
*How to Ask Good Questions* https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 
- you'll get better feedback and helpful answers if you put some thought in to your problem before coming to SO for help, and by including a specific problem with code *that you've tried* showing effort to solve the problem yourself. You can edit your post once you have an idea of the specific issue.